# How to pass version of CustomTool in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have a jenkinsfile where a custom tool, which is installed on the jenkins server, is downloaded and used inside a script:

```
script {
          withEnv(["myCustomToolPath=${tool name: 'my-custom-tool', type: 'com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.customtools.CustomTool'}"]) {
                    dir ("${myCustomToolPath}") {
....
}
```

Now I need to have different versions of that tool.
In the jenkins global tool configuration, I can check "Enable Version" at my tool and set the available versions.
This is documented at the custom tools plugin site using a parametrized build when starting the build from the web UI.

How can I pass the version from my jenkinsfile to the tool, instead of choosing it in the UI?
I didn't find anything documented.

I thought about something like this:

```
def TOOL_VERSION = 1.1.0

 withEnv(["myCustomToolPath=${tool name: 'my-custom-tool', version: ${TOOL_VERSION} type: 'com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.customtools.CustomTool'}"]) {
```

(Side question: Would that nested parameter even work?)

Comment: Are you uaing either plugins ; [Extra Tool](https://plugins.jenkins.io/extra-tool-installers) or  [Custom Tool](https://plugins.jenkins.io/custom-tools-plugin) plugin?

Comment: Yes, I am using the Custom Tool plugin

Comment: Unfortunately, Jenkins API does not support this behaviour. As far as I'm concerned, the only option to do so is to hack the system and use a custom "custom installer" which is dynamically created & selected and has the version as part of a class instance. I struggle with this too, and will soon return with a hacky solution. Maybe I'll publish this as plugin afterwards.